# SwiftUI - Nested ForEach - iterating on indices in array of arrays. Problem with ID of the elements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to make a dynamic grouped list of objects divided into sections with detail view of each object and edit ability.

I have objects divided into 3 sections
I tried to group my data into dictionary of arrays `[Int:[Objects]]`

But i had problem with editing so i made an array of 3 arrays with my objects `[[objectsGrouped]]`

Now i want to iterate it with ForEach. 
In order to be able to edit i got a tip to iterate not on the objects but the indices.

It's working but SwiftUI has problem with identifying rows, since the indices of each array are the same. When i delete one row other rows randomly appear in wrong places.

```
@ObservedObject var objects = Objects()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<objects.objectsGrouped.count, id: \.self) { indexGroup in
                Section(header: CustomHeader(group: indexGroup, objects: self.objects), content: {
                    ForEach(0..<self.objects.objectsGrouped[indexGroup].count, id: \.self) { indexObject in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ObjectDetail(object: self.objects.objectsGrouped[indexGroup][indexObject]))
                            { ObjectRowView(object: self.objects.objectsGrouped[indexGroup][indexObject]) }
```

Every object has unique id property but i can't access it because i iterate on indices.

I found out that attaching `.id(self.objects.objectsGrouped[indexGroup][indexObject].id)` 
to ObjectRowView help a bit - on deletion rows don't appear in wrong places
 but still swiftUI has problem to animate the rows when i delete them

Comment: What was the problem editing? I ask because I have learned not to iterate using indices if you ever plan to delete: the List and ScrollViews have memory leaks and can retain index references causing views to trigger Index out of range exceptions - even if the views are no-longer visible.

Comment: I couldn't use binding in TextField with my dictionary (maybe i did something wrong) and it was a mess - the key to the value is an optional so i had to use ```If``` all the time and then force-unwrap because i can't use If-let in a struct (probably i did it wrong too) than when i deleted one row i had index out of range exception even tho the view was no longer visible - same as you wrote.

Comment: You have to be careful trying to edit-in-place the contents of dictionaries in Swift. Similarly, the lack of if-let in SwiftUI makes dealing with optionals more cumbersome than it could be. Often it is better to extract a value for editing (especially optionals) into a @Binding variable that can be passed into a view along with the logic to update the dictionary after a successfully completed edit. Or, you might give the Editing view the know-how to successfully edit and update the dictionary directly. The key is to not try to do too much in one place. Splitting things up reduces complexity.

Comment: In the above I reference dictionaries, but the same applies to multi-level arrays... The key is to use simple views wherever possible that only operate on a bite-sized chunk of data that is not optional. Then your view logic can be simple and easy to debug. Optionals can then be dealt-with using `if` constructs to decide whether to enable a particular view. Similarly making the setter logic explicit as a function can make the rest of the view much simpler.

Comment: Also... If your data is complex and/or hierarchical, you should wrap the raw dictionaries/arrays in either a struct or object that encapsulates the necessary business logic to manage the data - so that the Views are free to do what they do best - rendering and simple editing of fields.

Comment: Last one: The best way I have found to manage deep structures with SwiftUI is to give everything a unique ID, and then iterate using ForEach on the items themselves. Then I implement editing/manipulation/management routines that operate based on IDs contained within the entities - passing the IDs or entities around as appropriate between views. I find it is easier to use @ObservedObjects than @State/@Binding structs for anything but the simplest of data, but then I have to deal with the complexities of hierarchical ObjectWillChange publishers - which is a topic unto itself....

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the tips. For now its working well, only thing is that on deletion swiftUI makes weird animation. But it's just my learning project, I will try to improve it and learn on it.