# How to use a default .onDelete in a ForEach

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I'm pretty familiar with the `.onDelete(perform:)` that comes out of the box with SwiftUI. This works really nicely with `.toolbar` and `EditButton()`

But here is my problem

I have a `ForEach` that iterates over *another* `ForEach`! and I can't just use the regular .onDelete(perform: ) because the delete method that I use would have to be different from the signature that the compiler expects..

I couldn't use `deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet)` because I have to pass in the index of the nested `ForEach` also I would have to use `deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet, itemIndex: Int)`.

(I'm getting the index of the nested `ForEach` with `zip`)

So I've never encountered this problem before so I'm a bit confused.

Here is the code snippet

```
             List {
                    ForEach(ticket.jobArray, id: \.self) { ticket in
                        ForEach(Array(zip(ticket.filters.indices, ticket.filters)), id: \.0) { index, filter in
                            Text(filter)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    EditButton()
```

I will also post a reproducible code snippet if anyone thinks its necessary.

Comment: Try to search, there are a lot of posts with .onDelete and EditButton.

Comment: I have been searching, its not much on the *nested* `ForEach` . And the only topic I found so far has no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371385/swiftui-nested-foreach-iterating-on-indices-in-array-of-arrays-problem-with